# email to post author in single page wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want to do this one thing in my single page template (Wordpress).
in my multiauthor blog, after each post, there is a author box contains a brief about the author.

i want to have a feature where readers can click a link and email the author of the post. The email feature will be like a thickbox/jquery popup email form without displaying the author's email address.

i have search the net for plugin that can do this but none is working this way.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is a sister site of stackoverflow that deals specifically with wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin "Lightbox Plus" allows you to build secondary lightboxes; I've used this for a lightboxed contact form before. I can't really help you beyond that given there's no code in this question; feel free to update it and I can help further.

Edit: 
The following code snippet uses Contact Form 7; replace the line with "do_shortcode();" with whatever form handling you're using. Or use Contact Form 7, it's pretty great.

In Lightbox Plus settings, enable inline lightboxes in "Lightbox Plus - Enable Optional/Advanced Settings". In your template, add:

```
<span id="contact-email"><a href="#" class="lbp-inline-link-1">your@emailhere</a>
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="lbp-inline-content-1" style="padding: 10px;">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form 1 "Contact form 1"]'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

...Replace the text in the php line with do_shortcode(); with whatever the shortcode for your email form is. Make sure to put it between single quotes!

Comment: how to make a lightboxed contact form?